# Can the HTML 5 cache manifest be hosted on another server? Can it reference files local to it using a relative path?

Tags: html, caching, manifest

I have an application which, for various reasons, needs to have the content split between hosts.

`http://mainsite.org/index.html` serves the main html file, which loads javascript and other cachable resources from `http://otherhost.com`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="http://otherhost.com/app.manifest">
    ...
</html>
```

What I want to be able to do, is specify in `http://mainsite.org/index.html` to load the html 5 manifest from `http://otherhost.com/app.manifest` and have that manifest file contain references (ideally relative) to all of the cacheable resources found on `http://otherhost.com`

Is this possible? Can the HTML 5 cache manifest be hosted on another server?

Can it reference files local to it using a relative path?